# Loop through a bunch of variables using a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have 4 domains that I want to check in my cron every hour. It checks if a word exists, and if it doesn't it will reboot the machine. In my example below I have 4 domains I am checking, but how do I loop through these variables in an if statement without having to replicate this 4 times in my bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

webserv1="domain1.com"
webserv2="domain2.com"
webserv3="domain3.com"
webserv4="domain4.com"

Keyword="helloworld" # enter the keyword for test content


if (curl -s "$webserv1" | grep "$keyword") 
then
        echo " the website is working fine"
else
        sudo reboot
fi

if (curl -s "$webserv2" | grep "$keyword") 
then
        echo " the website is working fine"
else
        sudo reboot
fi

if (curl -s "$webserv3" | grep "$keyword") 
then
        echo " the website is working fine"
else
        sudo reboot
fi

if (curl -s "$webserv4" | grep "$keyword") 
then
        echo " the website is working fine"
else
        sudo reboot
fi
```

Comment: Instead of separate variables put them all into an array

Comment: The parentheses around conditions aren't necessary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note that you can reduce repetition without necessarily using a loop. Define a function to abstract out the common part, then call the function multiple times.

```
#!/bin/bash

webserv1="domain1.com"
webserv2="domain2.com"
webserv3="domain3.com"
webserv4="domain4.com"

check () {
  if curl -s "$1" | grep "$keyword"; then
    echo "the website $1 is working fine"
  else
    sudo reboot
  fi
}

check "$webserv1"
check "$webserv2"
check "$webserv3"
check "$webserv4"
```

Answer (score 3):

Array approach would be :

```
arr=(a1.com a2.com a3.com) ## Define an array with values

#Loop through all the array values

for val in "${arr[@]}"
do
echo $val
done
```

The output would be :

```
a1.com
a2.com
a3.com
```

Your script would look like this :

```
webservers=(domain1.com domain2.com domain3.com domain4.com)
Keyword="helloworld"

for webserver in "${webservers[@]}"
do
    if (curl -s "$webserver" | grep "$keyword")
    then
        echo " the website $webserver is working fine"
    else
        sudo reboot
    fi
done
```

Comment: `"${arr[@]}"`, please. It's a good habit, and it costs almost nothing.

Comment: @rici Done. Thanks.

Comment: The array is a convenience; the same loop could be written by hardcoding the sequence instead of defining the array first.

Comment: @chepner That is correct. But if in case we want to use it in multiple loops then I think it would become tedious to write the hardcoding sequence again and again. That is why I just defined it on top.

Answer (score 1):

You would make an array and loop through like this:

```
for d in domain1.com domain2.com domain3.com
do
  echo $d
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated using chepner answer and also added in another parameter:

> #!/bin/bash
>
> sv2="http://yyyy/get_info"
>   sv3="http://zzzz/get_info"
>   key1="xxxx"
>   key2="yyy"
>   key3="uuu"
>
> check () {
>     if curl -s "$1" | grep "OK"; then
>       echo "${1} ${2} - GOOD - $(date)"
>     else
>       curl -H 'API-Key: XXXXX' https://____/server/reboot --data "ID=${2}"
>       echo "REBOOT ----- ${1}"
>     fi
>   }
>   check "$sv1" "$key1"
>   check "$sv2" "$key2"
>   check "$sv3" "$key3"sv1="http://xxx/get_info"